Extremal number for $K_4$ without an edge
I'm studying some graph theory and I'm trying to do an exercise which asks to determine $ex(n , H)$ (which's the maximum number of edges on a graph with $n$ vertices not containing an isomorphic copy of $H$) for $H$ being $K_4$ without a diagonal edge, so that it looks like two glued triangles. I've tried imitating Mantel's theorem proof which's in the textbook, but it seems like I'm ending up with a worse bound, so I don't know how to proceed.
The exercise has a hint: if $G$ has triangles, take a triangle $T$ and look at $G^\prime = G \setminus T$. How many neighbors in $T$ does each vertex in $G^\prime$ has?
The hint seems to point out to an imitation of Mantel's theorem proof. Since each vertex has at most one neighbor in $T$ (otherwise we have our copy of $H$), we have the inequality
$$e(G) \leq e(G^\prime) + n - 3 + 3$$
However iterating this process until $G^\prime$ is triangle-free seems to lead to a worse upper bound than that of Mantel's theorem. Am I thinking about it the wrong way?
Any help, and especially hints or indirect answers are appreciated.

You haven't made any mistakes in what you've done so far; "iterating this process until $G'$ is triangle-free" seems like the way to go. Maybe you should elaborate on what you do from there, until you reach a conclusion that seems clearly wrong to you?

@MishaLavrov By iterating I arrived at an upper bound of $\frac{(n - t)^2}{4} + tn - 3\frac{t(t-1)}{2}$ ($t$ the number of triangles), but this seems to be smaller than the one given by Mantel's theorem, and since every triangle-free graph is $H$-free as well, it seems like this is useless to determine $ex(n, H)$.

It is perfectly correct to say that if this process can be iterated $t$ times, then the original $n$-vertex $H$-free graph has at most $$\frac{(n-3t)^2}{4} + n + (n-3) + \dots + (n-3t+3) = \frac{(n-3t)^2}{4} + tn - 3\frac{t(t-1)}{2}$$ edges. It can be a little bit tricky, however, to interpret what this means.
First of all, let's backtrack and understand what kind of answer we can expect to get. Two things are known:

The complete bipartite graph $K_{n/2,n/2}$ (or $K_{(n-1)/2, (n+1)/2}$ if $n$ is odd) is a triangle-free graph with $\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor$ edges, so in particular it's an $H$-free graph with this many edges. This tells us that $\operatorname{ex}(n,H) \ge \lfloor \frac{n^2}{4}\rfloor$.
By the Erdős–Stone theorem, $\operatorname{ex}(n,H) \le (1+o(1))\frac{n^2}{4}$. So the true answer is at most slightly bigger.

Second, when we consider the statement "the $n$-vertex $H$-free graph $G$ has at most $\frac{(n-3t)^2}{4} + tn - 3\frac{t(t-1)}{2}$ edges", it's important to realize that we have no control over $t$: it depends on $G$, and possibly on the triangles we end up deleting. It's not a statement that says "For all $t$, the graph $G$ has at most ... edges"; rather, for every graph $G$, there exists some $t$ such that $G$ has at most that many edges.
If we play around with the bound $\frac{(n-3t)^2}{4} + tn - 3\frac{t(t-1)}{2}$, we realize that for $n>6$, it is maximized at $t=0$; setting $t$ to a positive value gets us a smaller number of edges than $\frac{n^2}{4}$. This is not a problem! What it tells us is this:
For $n>6$, the extremal $H$-free graphs are exactly the extremal triangle-free graphs.
Only for $n=1,\dots,6$ is it possible that we observe a difference between excluding $K_3$ and excluding $H$!
(There is only a numerical difference when $n=3$: here, the largest triangle-free graph has $2$ edges, but the largest $H$-free graph has $3$ edges. But there is a difference in extremal constructions up to $n=6$. For example, the triangular prism graph is a $6$-vertex, $9$-edge $H$-free graph: an equally good alternative to $K_{3,3}$.)

We can arrive at the same conclusion without optimizing over $t$. For example, we can prove by induction on $n$ that $\operatorname{ex}(n,H) \le \frac{n^2}{4}$ for all sufficiently large $n$ - actually, for all $n>3$. Check this for $n=4,5,6$ as base cases. For $n>6$, consider two possibilities:

The triangle-free graphs all have at most $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges by Mantel's theorem.
The $H$-free graphs with a triangle have at most $\operatorname{ex}(n-3,H) + n$ edges, which is at most $\frac{(n-3)^2}{4} + n$ by the induction hypothesis. Expanding this out, we get $\frac{n^2}{4} - \frac14(2n-9)$, which is less than $\frac{n^2}{4}$.

We conclude that $\operatorname{ex}(n,H) \le \frac{n^2}{4}$ for all $n>3$ by induction on $n$.

Thank you very much! I thought I could arrive at your conclusion, but was skeptical it was the case.

Very understandable! This is one of those cases where the calculations are quick, but understanding what they mean takes some time.

Some intuition could also be had from observing what happens when one adds an edge to the extremal examples in Mantel's theorem, i.e., complete bipartite graphs. One creates not only triangles, but (many) copies of $K_4$ minus an edge. If the extremal number was greater than $\frac{n^2}{4}$, the extremal examples for $K_4$ minus an edge would  have to look very different from complete bipartite graphs.
